# Tab from Salesforce Lightning RECORD page is unavailable in mobile, except for some iOS versions

Tags: visualforce, lightning, salesforce1-app, mobile

I created a New Tab in Salesforce Lightning Record Page and the same contained a VF Page. The same is not visible in Mobile App except for some latest iOS versions, that Salesforce has recently released under Beta version.
I am aware that the support for yet is not available and would not prefer the option to display the same as Mobile Cards or Quick Links Option.

Any alternatives or help in the matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Now with the latest release of Salesforce Mobile app version, now the tabs added in desktop version automatically get added into the mobile app also.

Just enable 'New Salesforce Mobile App' user permission to certain/all users & then you are good to go.

Refer this link: [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_mobile_app_new_user_perm.htm)

I too needed this feature & by doing so, it worked.